# how to update service provider in wso2 using soap request with inbound saml web sso configuration details: need soap request

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

currently working on wso2 identity servicer v5.7 . need a help to update service provider using soap request. i read the wso2 docs and saw the services provided by wso2 but did not find the right soap request. I want to update service provider all the details in one request: saml sso configuration as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `updateApplication` method of `IdentityApplicationManagementService` to update a Service Provider. To obtain the WSDL, use the following URL.

`https://{IShost}:{port}/services/IdentityApplicationManagementService?wsdl`

Comment: I am using createApplication for creating service provider but i want to update service provider using update soap request

Comment: For that, you can use the `updateApplication` method of the `IdentityApplicationManagementService`. You can update all the details with that request. Check the WSDL file

Comment: Yes i know updateApplication is there for update the service provider details but unable to find details about under inbound section - saml2 sso configuration details that is my problem. if you know the  complete soap request please share with me. Thankyou!